# What is the total variation of a dirac delta function $\delta(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, definition, dirac-delta, bounded-variation

What is the [total variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation) of a dirac delta function $\delta(x)$? My guess is that it is something like $\infty$. If not defined, what would be the best way to define?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44794/discussion-on-question-by-rajesh-dachiraju-what-is-the-total-variation-of-a-dira).

Comment: @PedroTamaroff : When you move things to "chat", the MathJax within the comments doesn't get rendered.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You have to use ChatJax or its variants.

Comment: Here, when you say dirac do you mean that it takes values $1$ and $0$ or values $0$ and $\infty$?  I'm guessing the later...?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(f_1,f_2,f_3,\ldots)$ be any sequence of functions of bounded variation such that, given any continuous function $g$,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_ng=g(0).$$(Of course, there are many such sequences, but the argument is independent of that.) Then$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathrm{TV}(f_n)=\infty.$$This is one way to interpret your question, and then the answer is indeed $\infty$.

Comment: I think pretty much the only other interpretation that makes any sense is to think of $\delta$ as a measure and then consider its total variation. (This interpretation gives a different result of course.)

Comment: Yes, but that seems to me to be misinterpreting the original question, which seems to want $\delta$ to be a generalized function.  You can formalize some generalized functions as measures, but in this formalism, an ordinary function $f$ (if integrable) is represented by the signed measure $A \mapsto \int_A f$, and the total variation of this measure is not the total variation of $f$.  So this is not giving us a notion of the total variation of a generalized function, but rather a notion of the total variation of an indefinite integral of a generalized function.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify this, lets agree on the definitions of which we're using.  Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space.

For any measure $\mu$ on $(X,\Sigma)$ define, the upper and lower variation (respectively) as follows
$$
\overline{\mathrm{W}}(\mu,E)=\sup\left\{\mu(A)\mid A\in\Sigma\text{ and }A\subset E \right\}\qquad\forall E\in\Sigma\\
\underline{\mathrm{W}}(\mu,E)=\inf\left\{\mu(A)\mid A\in\Sigma\text{ and }A\subset E \right\}\qquad\forall E\in\Sigma.
$$
From this, we may define the total variation (extended-value) *"norm"* of a measure as follows
$$
\|\mu\|_{TV}\triangleq \sup_{E \in \Sigma} \left(
\overline{\mathrm{W}}(\mu,E) + \left| \underline{\mathrm{W}}(\mu,E)\right|
\right)
= \overline{\mathrm{W}}(\mu,X) + \left| \underline{\mathrm{W}}(\mu,X)\right|
.
$$
Let's make some computations:

**Definition 1: Probability**
If the Dirac delta refers to the degenerate probability measure, defined by:
$$\delta_B(A)\triangleq \begin{cases}
1 : & A \cap B\neq\emptyset\\
0 : & \mbox{else}\\
\end{cases},
$$
then
$$
\overline{\mathrm{W}}(\mu,X)=\sup\left\{\delta(A)\mid A\in\Sigma\text{ and }A\subset E \right\}=
\delta(B)=1.  
$$
Similarly the lower variation is minimized by $B^c$ (possibly empty) and takes value $0$.  Therefore, 
$$
\|\delta_B\|_{TV}=1<\infty.
$$

**Definition 2: Physics**
Fix some $x \in X$ and define the Dirac delta (generalized) function as
$$
\delta_x(A)\triangleq \begin{cases}
\infty : & x \in A\\
0 : & x \not\in A
\end{cases}
,$$
The analogous argument shows that the upper variation on $X$ is $\infty$, and is maximized by $\{x\}$.  Likewise, the lower variation is minimized to value $0$ (if $\# X>1$).  Hence
$$
\|\delta\|_{TV}=\infty
.
$$

So it really depends on what you mean by "Dirac Delta" function.